# Enterprise application vs Normal application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enterprise

Can someone easily make me understand what is Enterprise Application? What is the difference between Enterprise and Normal application? Why Java is used most to build Enterprise applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin fowler in his book, [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html), defines Enterprise Applications like this:

> Enterprise applications usually involve **persistent data**. The data is
>   persistent because it needs to be around between multiple runs of the
>   program—indeed, it usually needs to persist for several years. Also
>   during this time there will be many changes in the programs that use
>   it. It will often outlast the hardware that originally created much of
>   it, and outlast operating systems and compilers. During that time
>   there'll be many changes to the structure of the data in order to
>   store new pieces of information without disturbing the old pieces.
>   Even if there's a fundamental change and the company installs a
>   completely new application to handle a job, the data has to be
>   migrated to the new application.
>
> There's usually **a lot of data**—a moderate system will have over 1 GB of
>   data organized in tens of millions of records—so much that managing it
>   is a major part of the system. Older systems used indexed file
>   structures such as IBM's VSAM and ISAM. Modern systems usually use
>   databases, mostly relational databases. The design and feeding of
>   these databases has turned into a subprofession of its own.
>
> Usually many people access data **concurrently**. For many systems this
>   may be less than a hundred people, but for Web-based systems that talk
>   over the Internet this goes up by orders of magnitude. With so many
>   people there are definite issues in ensuring that all of them can
>   access the system properly. But even without that many people, there
>   are still problems in making sure that two people don't access the
>   same data at the same time in a way that causes errors. Transaction
>   manager tools handle some of this burden, but often it's impossible to
>   hide this from application developers.
>
> With so much data, there's usually a **lot of user interface screens** to
>   handle it. It's not unusual to have hundreds of distinct screens.
>   Users of enterprise applications vary from occasional to regular, and
>   normally they will have little technical expertise. Thus, the data has
>   to be presented lots of different ways for different purposes. Systems
>   often have a lot of batch processing, which is easy to forget when
>   focusing on use cases that stress user interaction
>
> Enterprise applications rarely live on an island. Usually they need to
>   **integrate** with other enterprise applications scattered around the
>   enterprise.The various systems are built at different times with
>   different technologies, and even the collaboration mechanisms will be
>   different

He also enumerate some of common examples of Enterprise Applications:

> Enterprise applications include payroll, patient records, shipping
>   tracking, cost analysis, credit scoring, insurance, supply chain,
>   accounting, customer service, and foreign exchange trading. Enterprise
>   applications don't include automobile fuel injection, word processors,
>   elevator controllers, chemical plant controllers, telephone switches,
>   operating systems, compilers, and games.

Answer (score 1):

An enterprise application (Java EE application) is a server application deployed to a Java EE application server. The application server provides you all the important and often hard to implement features like server socket management, multi-threading, clustering, security, resource/ database access management, declarative transaction handling, dependency injection and much more.

Eg. with JAX-RS you can write a full-blown RESTFul webservice with a simple POJO and just a couple of annotations. The application server then makes sure that the HTTP requests are routed correctly to your annotated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise applications are deployed in the application server and are developed mainly using three layers,

1. **User interface** layer which uses presentation logic to display user interface to the client. Technologies used are HTML, JSP etc
2. **Business layer** which uses business logic and processes the requests to fulfill requirements of the client. Technologies like JSP, Servlets, EJB's are used.
3. **Data persistence or access** layer which uses persistence logic to interact with the database and perform queries. Technologiess like Hibernate, JDBC are used.